# Remove/Substitute concurrent double quotes in unix

Tags: unix

How to substitute recurring double quotes?
For example, the below line

```
"I need help with ""Unix"" scripting"
```

need to be changed to

```
"I need help with 'Unix' scripting"
```

that is, substituting "" with '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ var='"I need help with ""Unix"" scripting"'
$ echo $var
"I need help with ""Unix"" scripting"
$ echo $var | sed 's/""/'"'"'/g'
"I need help with 'Unix' scripting"
```